# Sort array of years (including BCE)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

There is an array of objects containing a chemical element with it's discovery year:

```
[
   {"name": "hydrogen", "discovered": "1766"},
   {"name": "boron", "discovered": "1808"},
   {"name": "copper", "discovered": "9000 BCE"},
   {"name": "argon", "discovered": "1894"},
   {"name": "iron", "discovered": "before 5000 BCE"},
   {"name": "phosphorus", "discovered": "1669"}
]
```

What I want is to sort the array in terms of the year discovered, so the oldest (copper in this case) should be the first item and the recent(argon) should be the last item.

```
//It should look like this in the end:
[
   {"name": "copper", "discovered": "9000 BCE"},
   {"name": "iron", "discovered": "before 5000 BCE"},
   {"name": "phosphorus", "discovered": "1669"},
   {"name": "hydrogen", "discovered": "1766"},
   {"name": "boron", "discovered": "1808"},
   {"name": "argon", "discovered": "1894"}
]
```

The problem I encountered was the few keywords like "before", "BCE", "CE", that I don't know how to handle.

Is there any solution to handle this problem?

Comment: Are the unknown keywords always the same? `before`, `BCE`, `CE`?

Comment: yes, you need to handle things like `before` and `BCE` and `CE`  .... `BCE` is easy .... e.g. 1000 BCE is `-1000` .... though ... why would you put `before 5000 BCE` before `9000 BCE` ... since before 5000 BCE could be 5001 BCE ... which is AFTER 9000 BCE ... so, how to handle that is a real problem only you can decide

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake while editing the question. I fixed it now

Comment: @Titulum yes, the keywords are always same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`9000 BCE` is same as year `-9000`.

You can simply treat those `BCE` (keyword `before` might be ignored, cause it contains `BCE` anyway) data strings as `-year` in `sort` function, as follows:

```js
const data = [{name:"hydrogen",discovered:"1766"},{name:"boron",discovered:"1808"},{name:"copper",discovered:"9000 BCE"},{name:"argon",discovered:"1894"},{name:"iron",discovered:"before 5000 BCE"},{name:"phosphorus",discovered:"1669"}];

const res = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const numA = (a.discovered.includes("BCE") ? -1 : 1)
              * a.discovered.replace(/\D/g, '')
  const numB = (b.discovered.includes("BCE") ? -1 : 1)
              * b.discovered.replace(/\D/g, '')
  return numA - numB
})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Comment: Nice! But needs to reverse. The guy wanted `copper` to be the first one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so first you need to create a function that will convert the dates to a common format. In this example I will convert it to a number relative to 0 (year 0):

```js
const beforeRegExp = new RegExp('(before )\\d*( BCE)');
const bceRegExp = new RegExp('\\d*( BCE)');

function toCommonDateFormat(date) {
  if (beforeRegExp.test(date)) {
    return date.replace("before ", "").replace(" BCE", "") * -1
  } else if (bceRegExp.test(date)) {
    return date.replace(" BCE", "") * -1
  } else {
    return date * 1;
  }
}
```

Now we can use this function in a sort function:

```js
function compareDates(firstDate, secondDate) {
  return toCommonDateFormat(firstDate) - toCommonDateFormat(secondDate);
}
```

And now, to tie it all together:

```js
const list = [{
    "name": "hydrogen",
    "discovered": "1766"
  },
  {
    "name": "boron",
    "discovered": "1808"
  },
  {
    "name": "copper",
    "discovered": "9000 BCE"
  },
  {
    "name": "argon",
    "discovered": "1894"
  },
  {
    "name": "iron",
    "discovered": "before 5000 BCE"
  },
  {
    "name": "phosphorus",
    "discovered": "1669"
  }
]

const beforeRegExp = new RegExp('(before )\\d*( BCE)');
const bceRegExp = new RegExp('\\d*( BCE)');

function toCommonDateFormat(date) {
  if (beforeRegExp.test(date)) {
    return date.replace("before ", "").replace(" BCE", "") * -1
  } else if (bceRegExp.test(date)) {
    return date.replace(" BCE", "") * -1
  } else {
    return date * 1;
  }
}

function compareDates(firstDate, secondDate) {
  return toCommonDateFormat(firstDate) - toCommonDateFormat(secondDate);
}

const orderedList = list.sort(function(firstItem, secondItem) {
  return compareDates(firstItem.discovered, secondItem.discovered);
});

console.log(orderedList);
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same sorting function for objects like this : {"name":  "silver", "discovered": "before 3000 BC"} where the "before christ" is also included. It would be of great help

Comment: Yes, you just need to add an `if` case to the `toCommonDateFormat` function.